# Format specifies type 'char *', but the argument has type 'char **'

Tags: c, cgi

I have tried printing the output by hard coding it, but I'm getting an error because the argument I gave is type `char**` and the format in `printf` is specifying type char*.

Also there are four lines of code which I did not understand (see code comments in the below code), so it would be really helpful is someone explains that block of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void inputParsing(char *src, char *end, char *destU, char *destP) {
    int x = 0;
    for(; src != end; src++){
        if((*src != '+') && x==0) {
            *destU = *src;
            destU++;
        }
        else if((*src != '+') && x==1){
            *destP = *src;
            destP++;
        }
        else {
            x = 1;
        }
    }
    *destU = ' ';                  //What does this line do?
    *destP = ' ';                  //What does this line do?
    *++destU = '0';                //What does this line do?
    *++destP = '0';                //What does this line do?
    printf("%s\n",&destU);
    printf("%s\n",&destP);
}

void inputStoring() {
    char inputArray[200];
    char usernameArray[200];
    char passwordArray[200];
    //int n = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    //fgets(inputArray, n+1, stdin);
    strcpy(inputArray, "gaming+koko");
    int n = strlen(inputArray);
    inputParsing(inputArray, inputArray + n, usernameArray, passwordArray); //inputArray+n is referencing the array cell that contains the last inputted character.
}

int main(void) {
    inputStoring();
}
```

Comment: Where did this code come from?  What is the purpose of it?  (Without knowing this, we could only speculate at the purpose of individual lines...)

Comment: I would think you'd be more interested in what the two lines *after* the ones you marked do, since they're the ones that invoke *undefined behavior* in your program. The marked lines just used a pointer dereference operator to store single chars in the provide buffers from the caller. (incrementing the storage locations with the second pair).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I wrote this code to get input from a website by the method POST. So basically im storing the input in inputArray and then calling the method inputParsing to separate the username and password and storing them in two different arrays.

Comment: If *you* wrote this code, why are you asking *us* what the purpose of those lines is?

Comment: @WhozCraig - Yeah I understood what the marked lines did, but what I dont understand is why I need to do that. I copied that portion from my professors notes so Im not sure why its required.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I explained why Im asking the purpose of those lines in my previous comment. If you don't feel like helping then feel free to not comment :)

Comment: @user1836292: I'm commenting to encourage you to *clarify your question*.  Clearer questions get better help faster ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting the `char*` vs `char**`-issue and the `'0'` vs `'\0'`-issue

```
*++destU = '\0';                //What does this line do?
*++destP = '\0';                //What does this line do?
printf("%s\n",destU);
printf("%s\n",destP);
```

the code still does nothing useful, because `destU` and `destP` will each point to a null-byte, which means `printf()` will hit `'\0'` as the first character, and won't print anything.
You should probably explain what the code is *supposed* to do, so we can say where it's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks now I understood why it wasnt printing what I wanted it to print. I can fix the rest now.

Answer (score 0):

destU and destP in your code are char*. But you are passing them in printf with a & sign meaning that u pass their address so the printf gets an address to a character pointer.

U need to pass just destU and destP to printf functions as

```
printf("%s\n",destU);
printf("%s\n",destP);
```

Here is a small guide on pointers i found by a simple search on Google
http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

```
*destU = ' ';         /*Sets "space character" or ' ' at the current destU pointer position*/        
*destP = ' ';         /*Same but for destP*/                  
*++destU = '0';       /*Moves pointer position by 1 place forward and sets a value 0 byte in its place - this is not a string terminating value (\0 is) so u may have problems when trying to print the string thank you EOF for correcting*/
*++destP = '0';      /*Same but for destP*/
```

also the inputArray+n will be a \0 byte value so u can just ask if the value is \0 (every string is terminated with a \0)

Comment: `'0'` is **not** a null-terminator. `'\0'` is.

Comment: Now after changing the code according to what you posted, shouldn't the first printf print "gaming" and the second one print "koko"? But when I run my program it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Yes because of the ='0' u need to put '\0' there instead.

Comment: @daniels_pa - I changed that too but it only prints a new blank line, nothing else :/

Comment: Yes because you destU and destP pointers are not moved to the beginning so they are used in the string from the current position (which is null byte - hence the string is imediatly terminated).

U need to safe the pointers for the beginning of destU and destP and  set destU and destP pointers to them before trying to print them.

Add in code [code]
    char *save_dU; /*this at the beginning of inputParsing method*/
    char *save_dP;
    save_dU=destU;
    save_dP=destP;
[/code]
and before calling printf 
[code]
    destU=save_dU;
    destP=save_dP;
[/code]